# Alternatives to EntLib caching application block?

Tags: .net, caching, client

I'm developing a windows client app and would like to cache some data. It's a pretty simple scenario, basically just keeping some data in memory so the app can avoid crashing if the network connection drops out.

I could roll my own cache solution, or use the EntLib caching block, but am looking for a few more alternatives before committing to something.
The problem is, all the searches I've done either show:

- The entlib block (which I already know about)
- The ASP.NET cache (which I can't use)
- Velocity (which is distributed, and requires a windows service to connect to)
- NCache (also distributed, similar to velocity)

Surely there are some other in-memory caching libraries out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

.Net 4.0 introduced the [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642.aspx) namespace.  It's recommended for memory caching going forward, per the MSDN documentation: [Caching in .NET Framework Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx).  It's modeled similarly to the System.Web.Caching implementation pre-4.0, so ASP.NET users should be relatively familiar with its use.

Answer (score 1):

Any caching I have done in winforms I have done with static variables, but if I were doing something non trivial, I would probably be using a DI framework and just use its caching. http://blogs.conchango.com/owainwragg/archive/2008/10/31/caching-with-castle-windsor.aspx

Not a complete solution though. It makes sense for caching of objects returned from the DI kernel, but not nessicarily arbitrary values.

Comment: What has a DI container got to do with caching? I can see that windsor obviously provides this functionality in a rich way, but why on earth would you do that?

Comment: well, a DI container is there to handle returning dependencies, how it returns them could be considered part of its purview.

Comment: good point, and this makes sense if you're returning objects out of your DI container... It seems like the wrong thing if I just want to cache say a large chunk of XML or similar though...

Comment: Yeah, you've got me there. guess i didn't fully think through the problem. Edited my answer.